# How to pass data to injected django template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

In django admin interface I have a custom tab for displaying a table. How to display the table as django admin model list table instead of field, but get the context for table from admin.py by calling the method from the model. I used django-baton's `baton_form_includes` to insert a template below the field, but then I could not pass data to that template.

`models.py`

```
class MyModel(TimeStampedModel):
.
.
.
def get_custom_tab_data(self):
    return OtherModel.objects.filter(
        active=False
    )
```

`admin.py`

```
@admin.register(models.MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin():
.
.
.
readonly_fields = (
    "get_custom_tab_data",
)
fieldsets = (
    _("Custom Tab"),
    {
        "fields": ("get_custom_tab_data"),
        "classes": ("tab-fs-custom")
    }
)
.
.
# django-baton
baton_form_includes = [("admin/custom_tab_template.html", "get_custom_tab_data", "below")]

# This was the better solution but template table should display as model admin list with custom data, so had to use baton_form_includes to inject template above field.
# def custom_tab_data(self, myModel: models.MyModel):
    #     if myModel.active:
    #         return "N/A"

    #     if custom_data := myModel.get_custom_tab_data()[:15]: # get 15 latest
    #         html_content = render_to_string(
    #             "admin/custom_tab_template.html",
    #             {"custom_data": custom_data}
    #         )
    #         return mark_safe(html_content)

    @admin.display(description="Custom Tab")
    def get_custom_tab_data(self, myModel: models.MyModel):
        return self.custom_tab_data(account)
```

`custom_tab_template.html`

```
{% load i18n l10n %}
<table class="table table-stripped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% comment %} {% for data in original.get_custom_tab_data|slice:"-15:" %} {% endcomment %}
        {% for data in custom_data %}
        <tr>
            <th>{{ data.id }}</th>
            <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ data.state }}</td>
            <td>{{ data.created }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% empty %}
        <tr>
            <th>-</th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table
```